Rough feasability of 1W of microwave power in a 1mm^3 region at 10GHz?
I understand, from a previous question, that the generation and simulation of near-field microwave electronics is challenging.
Before doing a full simulation, is it possible to get a ballpark estimate for what a reasonable amount of microwave power is possible to generate in a small region (without enhancing it via a cavity)?
For example, what is the rough feasability of 1W of microwave power in a 1mm^3 region at 10GHz? It would be my first time trying something like this, and I want just a quick evaluation of people with more experience if this is a realistic goal.

What is the meaning of power delivered to a volume of undefined impedance? Would a microstrip transmission line not suffice?

@TimWilliams, perhaps I'll write a new question to explain the details. But the context is: I was origionally considering a microwave cavity at 10GHz, and I wanted to see if I could produce the same field strength for a small region inside the cavity, in an open configuration without a cavity at all.  I have a loose understanding that this should be equivalent to about 1W of microwave power in a 1mm^3 region -- but as you say, perhaps my estimate of power is not so clear.

Are you asking specifically about generation, ie. Feed X watts of DC into a cubic millimeter, then some fraction of it comes out as microwaves? Otherwise, what’s the purpose of the word generate? The limitations will be purely thermal, not much to do with RF. It is insanely hard to cool down a cubic mm even if everything around it is metal. The imaginary generator would be fed power via solid copper, and RF would exit via a copper transmission line with minimum of dielectric.

If you’re not generating the RF power, just passing it through dielectric, then 1W/mm^3 is not very much. Plenty of transmission lines do this day in, day out. So, is that what you are asking? You want about 1mm^3 of space, all of it presumably dielectric, right? There can be metal around it. Not even necessarily nearby - the cube can be inside a waveguide that’s pushing kilowatts out. So it looks like your question is sort of trivial, unless you can really explain what you mean. The lack of clarity makes it frustrating. You mean something - just say it, don’t save it for later.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, well perhaps you can assist me in the correct word choice. Here's another description for clarity:  if you imagine, for example, that I already have a microwave source, which is coupled in an SMA cable -- then my goal is to produce a certain field strength such that it corresponds to 1W of disappation of power from a standard SMA cable.

“Power dissipation from a standard cable” - you want the cable to be dissipating 1W per cubic mm as heat? There is something fundamental you’re not saying. You do understand that you can feed 10W at 20GHz into a small diameter cable, and there will be way more power passing through each cubic mm than 1W, right? There are radar systems that pass way more per cubic mm in waveguides at similar frequencies. So you probably are not asking about that. What is it then? I genuinely would like to know. It may be an interesting question after all.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica, I was origionally considering a microwave cavity at 10GHz that produced a sufficient amount of field strength inside the cavity. The cavity was pumped with a microwave source with .1W of power from a standard SMA connector that is critically coupled with a normal microwave antenna.  I want to replace the cavity with an open geometry, in which there is no cavity anymore, just an antenna. This means that I need to radiate out from an antenna significantly more field strength than the cavity system.

The region of the cavity I'm interested in is only 1/1000 the volume of the cavity, and the cavity has a finess of 10^4, so I'm loosely expecting that the amount of power that I'll need is 10x what was disappated from the cavity system, IF all of the power is distributed in this smaller volume (this 1mm^3). So I was looking for a ballpark if these numbers that I'm thinking about are reasonable or not. (But, I am gaining a better understanding that I likely need a prerequiste question to help make things more clear).

Something fundamental is missing. You don't dissipate power into a field strength.  Field is lossless, in and of itself. The field strength might be 1m, 1, 1k, who knows, V/m from a single watt input. It's arbitrary -- it depends on the electrode geometry and the losses of the system. Quasi-static (near) fields  represent capacitance and inductance, not resistance.

For example, a microwave oven at 2.45GHz might produce between 100s V/m (e.g. heating plenty of water) to perhaps over 10kV/m (unloaded) at various points within the chamber, from a ballpark 1kW input. That's without any impedance matching, and a not-particularly-high Q cavity (1000s?). With a higher Q and appropriate impedance matching, 1kW can probably make MV/m -- this will have to be in vacuum of course as it would simply create plasma in air.  Or down at 1W, say 30kV/m. Still more is possible with cryogenics (superconducting cavity).

Microwave power cannot be "concentrated" on scales below its wavelength. To get to 1mm scale, your frequency should be about 300GHz, not 10.
Roughly speaking :-)

Try and keep comments to discussion ideas and not calling people out.

@VoltageSpike Can you undelete my initial comment? It was addressing the same content as the current edit, so remains relevant context for readers. If it was worded improperly, that's understandable, but in that case an edit might suffice; but I also don't recall calling anyone out but rather the content so I'm a bit mystified by its removal. Otherwise, I'll replace it just as well.

This is true in the far field, with conventional optics, but is not true in general. Energy can easily be concentrated, in the near field, no cavity required: transmission lines work at arbitrarily small fractions of a wavelength. Rather, there's an upper limit (mode breakup) instead. A 1 mm cube region underneath a microstrip would make a fine TEM cell up to, say, 35GHz or so?

@VoltageSpike, this answer just misinterprets the question (which is what I was commenting on in my origional comment). I am asking for a rough estimate for the feasiblity of 1W of power at 10GHz in a small area (which, yes, is smaller than the waves wavelength, but is certainly not "impossible" like this answer suggests).

@StevenSagona, this is not a misinterpretation. You used the term "concentrated", which implies that you need 1W inside a 1mm3 volume, and nothing around. Similar to what an optical lens do in its focus. Maybe you need more academically-accurate formulations of what do you need or ask about.

I'm flagging this question to be removed.  Answerer is being pedantic on word choice (which has been removed for clarity), and it should be clear from the title and context that this is not an answer to the question.

Fwiw I also always interpreted it as RF powe in the volume and =0 elsewhere.
